# Find if values in data.frame are contained in min and max range of a second data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, find, range

I have two `data.frames` and I desire to know if the values in `df_1` are included in the min and max range of `df_2`.

Here my example:

```
df_1 = data.frame(x = c(0.5, 0.75, 0.15, 0.1))
df_2 = data.frame(min = c(0.2, 0.5, 0.1, 0.6), max = c(0.9, 0.6, 0.35, 1))
```

The desired output should be e.g. just a logical vector of TRUE or FALSE, and in this case the desired output is:

```
> out
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

It should be trivial but I couldn't find an answer so far.

Any suggestion will be grateful.

Comment: `df_2$min <= df_1$x & df_1$x <= df_2$max`

Comment: nice one. thanks. please post an answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need nothing but base R for this:

```
df_2$min <= df_1$x & df_1$x <= df_2$max
```

No need for `dplyr` or anything else in the `tidyverse`. If you really wanted it, though, you could always do:

```
dplyr::between(df_1$x, df_2$min, df_2$max)
```

for perhaps slightly better readability (albeit a little worse code-golf).

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this:

```
df_1$x %in% c(df_2$min, df_2$max)

[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Which also allows you to use it for indexing, for example:

```
df_1[df_1$x %in% c(df_2$min, df_2$max),]

[1] 0.5 0.1
```

Comment: Nothing in either method requires `tidyverse`. (BTW: the use of `require` in this situation might be a bit flawed: if the package is not present, it will merely *warn* and return `FALSE`, whereas in interactive use one generally prefers failure.)

Comment: Sorry. Don't know why I thought %in% is part of 'tidyverse'

Comment: It's the percent signs, I think ... I've seen it before, thinking it's party of `magrittr`'s tools that `dplyr` and family capitalize on. shrug :-)

Comment: Yes, it's part of `magrittr`. I think they own the percent sign now ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
df_1%>%
  dplyr::bind_cols(df_2)%>%
  mutate(res=if_else(x<min | x>max,F,T))%>%
  .[,"res"]
```